# SQL Server nested transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, nested

What is the need of nested transactions in SQL Server? Can anyone explain with real time example.

I have understood that any error/rollback in inner transactions will roll back all the transactions.

Comment: [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Answer (score 3):

Nested transactions in itself have little to no use in SQL Server (or most other DBMS), I believe only BerkelyDB [supports them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/gsg_txn/JAVA/nestedtxn.html).

However, in programming they DO have a use in my opinion, but mostly because of the code isolation/separation seen in most programming languages.

Imagine the following pseudo-code:

```
function dostuff()
{
    begin transaction
    //manage data changes
    commit transaction
}

function docomplexstuff()
{
    begin transaction
    //change some data
    dostuff()
    commit transaction
}

function whatever
{
    //do random stuff
    dostuff()
}
```

If you call docomplexstuff you would have a nested transaction, but that's mostly a side-effect. The inner transaction actually guarantees that a transaction is used when calling the dostuff method from whatever code path you might call the method and the docomplexstuff outer transaction guarantees that you have the data manipulation in that method as well as in the child method as a single transaction.

So in my opinion it's more of a guarantee that the atomicity of the inner transaction is guaranteed any way the code is called and also a guarantee that if you want the inner method executed within another transaction is committed as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The need for me is when doing Sql Server/Stored procedure unit tests.

Here's my example...

Create a procedure that does something for your application (inserts records into multiple tables) - wrap this whole thing in a transaction

Write a unit test to test that stored procedure. The way I write my unit tests, they always start with a `begin tran`, then execute the stored procedure that I'm trying to test, then rollback the transaction regardless of the outcome (you don't want your unit tests creating bad data in your database, even if it's in a Dev environment).